# Querying from parent table's data (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I have a parent table (`parent_table`) and few children tables inherit from it (`child_one_table` and `child_two_table`).

I want to query data using columns belong to the parent table only (the data itself is inserted to the children tables), when I run an `explain` on my query I see that there are sequence scans running on all the tables (`parent_table`, `child_one_table` and `child_two_table`).

Is there a more efficient way to do this? When I try to query using `ONLY` on  `parent_table` I get back 0 result since the data was inserted to children table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share more schema details about these tables and the query you are running? That would be helpful :-)

Comment: @Luke It's more of a theoretical question, but let's say ```parents table``` have ```id (uuid)```, ```name (text)``` and ```counter (number)``` columns. ```child_one_table``` inherits it and add ```country (text)``` column. ```child_two_table``` inherits it and add ```grade (number)``` column. When I query the data for ```SELECT * FROM parent_table WHERE name = 'joe';``` I see that it actually go over all 3 tables and query for that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying your question!

> When I query the data for `SELECT * FROM parent_table WHERE name = 'joe';` I see that it actually go over all 3 tables and query for that.

This seems to be standard behaviour from PostgreSQL. According to the `5.10.1. Caveats` section of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html

> Note that not all SQL commands are able to work on inheritance hierarchies. Commands that are used for data querying, data modification, or schema modification (e.g., `SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE`, most variants of `ALTER TABLE`, but not `INSERT` or `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME`) typically default to including child tables and support the ONLY notation to exclude them.

So really what you want to do is explore the usage of `ONLY` to specify the scope of your query.
I hope this can help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I insert my data I perform an ```INSERT``` to the children table, so when I tried query with ```FROM ONLY parent_table``` I got zero results (when I remove the ```ONLY``` I get some result). So is the problem is with the way I insert the data? Is there a "correct" way to insert for that matter?

Comment: That's correct, inheritance does not apply on `INSERT` nor `COPY`. That only affects the *specific* table you are targeting. This I believe is due to the different structure that tabls may have (documentation is not extremely clear about thtat). You could replicate the insert on child tables too, constraints are replicate upon creation, therefore you should be able to enforce integrity!